# Cannot SSH to my remote server from University network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I set up a small Ubuntu server at home for heavy calculations. I can SSH remotely to it from my other apartment without any problem. But when I am at the University, I cannot: after a while, it just says Connection TimeOut. I am using the Eduroam network, if this can be of help. What causes the problem? Is it possible to solve it?

Comment: (1) What client are you using?  (2) Can you run it in verbose mode and/or look at logs?  (3) Can you ssh into other servers from the university?  (4) What does the university IT staff say? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Your University could have network restrictions or a proxy blocking port 22. Use a VPN or similar to remedy this.

Comment: Is it still possible if I set up the server with another port?

Comment: Maybe but it depends on your Uni. Try to look into their policies to find out.

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/changing-the-ssh-port-for-your-linux-server-7306

Answer (score 1):

Eduroam mostly blocks most of the ports, and I think port 22 (SSH) is one of them. Using a VPN could work if the used ports here are not blocked either (which I assume they are). You could set up the port to 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) for example. These ports are not blocked, but notice that you have to disable the webserver at your server for this purpose.

Comment: This is very country-dependent, and organization-dependent as well. (Eduroam only centralises authentication, but you still use each organization's own Internet access.) For example, here in Europe, Eduroam policy usually says that 22 (SSH) _must be open_ in all institutions, even if the local IT staff might decide to block other ports. ([UK spec](https://community.ja.net/library/janet-services-documentation/eduroamuk-technical-specification) for comparison.)